# Go Interface memory leakage

Tags: go, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

seemly Go doesn't release interface based pointers properly.

```
package main //interface memory leakage

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

type Interface interface{ Method(v any) }
type Implementation struct{}

func (i *Implementation) Method(v any) {}

func main() {
    pages := Pages()
    fmt.Printf("First  Memory Usage: %dMB, expected 0\n", good())      // i:=&Implementation{}; i.Method(data)
    fmt.Printf("Second Memory Usage: %dMB, while expected 0\n", bad()) // var i Interface; i=&Implementation{}; i.Method(data)

    var xor byte //do somthing
    for j := 0; j < NUM_OF_PAGES; j++ {
        xor ^= pages[j][PAGE_SIZE-1]
    }
    print("xor: ", xor)
}

var data = "123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_"
var LOOP_SIZE = 3 * 1000 * 1000

const NUM_OF_PAGES = 10
const PAGE_SIZE = 1024 * 1024

func Pages() [][]byte {
    var pages [][]byte
    for j := 0; j < NUM_OF_PAGES; j++ {
        p := make([]byte, PAGE_SIZE)
        for i := 0; i < len(p); i++ {
            p[i] = 'A'
        }
        pages = append(pages, p)
    }
    return pages
}

func good() int64 {
    var m0, m1 runtime.MemStats
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m0)

    i := &Implementation{} //good line
    for n := 0; n < LOOP_SIZE; n++ {
        i.Method(data)
    }

    //runtime.GC()
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m1)
    return int64(m1.Alloc-m0.Alloc) / 1024 / 1024
}

func bad() int64 {
    var m0, m1 runtime.MemStats
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m0)

    var i Interface       //bad line
    i = &Implementation{} //bad line
    for n := 0; n < LOOP_SIZE; n++ {
        i.Method(data)
    }

    //runtime.GC()
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m1)
    return int64(m1.Alloc-m0.Alloc) / 1024 / 1024
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/0zlbPxs6WCV

here the code is same, first time Go release pointers but second time, when we are using interface based pointer likely go doesn't handle memory properly.
I showed the good and bad syntax within the code, what's difference between two syntax? why second line wastes memory()?

- first:    `i:=&Implementation{}; i.Method(data)`
- second:   `var i Interface; i=&Implementation{}; i.Method(data)`

Also the output shows the problem:

```
First  Memory Usage: 0MB, expected 0
Second Memory Usage: 27MB, while expected 0  //However the number is variable but almost is different significantly
```

I expect same result between first and second try.

Comment: Garbage collection runs globally on a schedule / quota system; just because some bytes have not been de-allocated 1 microsecond after use doesn't mean there is a memory leak problem.

Comment: In the hundreds of cases where someone claims here that Go has a memory leak, none have actually had a memory leak. If Go didn't collect pointers stored in interfaces it would be a massive bug, and should be reported in the Go issue tracker.

Comment: you are right. I may make a mistake. I am not sure that I am right. But the scenario is very special, It is really weird. superficially the combination of interface and slice or generic has unforeseeable behavior. @JimB

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I am not speaking about microsecond latency, in real high performance application, it uses 64GB memory less than some minutes and eventually the application is killed.

Comment: @BahadorNazariFard Can you provide some code to show and reproduce the memory leak? As others have said, the code you put here doesn't show any memory leak.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I think the code is clear. we shouldn't call runtime.GC() frequently, it shouldn't take a lot of memory at all, when all parameter is fixed. as my understanding, simply the both results should be same. why data:="1" uses a lot of memory while data:=1 uses no memory at all. what's the problem with slice/string parameter ?

Comment: How many bytes the data takes up and whether it requires heap allocation simply on the data-type, the length of the data, and which optimizations (if any) the compiler applies to that case.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Please consider that we expect no memory usage at all and it's correct when the argument is not slice, but in some case when the argument is slice/string/struct-contains-slice it takes extra unexpected memory. In local machine the difference is very high, the following lines shows near 2 GB, however I observed even 4GB difference.  first Memory Usage: 0MB, expected 0
Second Memory Usage: 1831MB, while expected 0

Comment: Slices data is heap allocated, so when you create a slice, some heap memory will be allocated to store the slice data.

Answer (score 2):

```golang
i := &Implementation{}
```

The first implementation is a pointer to a direct type.
No additional work needs to be done, because at compile time it is known which method needs to be invoked on the instance.

```golang
var i Interface
i = &Implementation{}
```

The second implementation boxes the pointer as an interface.
Because the value of `i` could be any value that satisfies the interface, it is not known which method needs to be executed, so more information needs to be stored in that variable.

When a pointer is boxed as an interface, it must store both the type of the pointer and the value of the pointer. So, an additional allocation must occur for that additional layer of indirection. Whether allocations are made on the heap or optimized onto the stack is determined by escape analysis.

Comment: in real code, I am using generic type, I removed all unnecessary extra codes. The sample code just shows the problem. Do you have any idea about the root cause? why whenever data is string or slice or struct that has slice , it uses a lot a memory, while even with big array it has not problem. do you have any idea? @tyler-kropp

Comment: as you know, the second way is correct and typical approach. in real application we are using second way always. why do we have a lot of memory usage when argument is a slice and or string? Do you have any Idea?

Comment: If you pass a string or a slice to a function, the compiler could end up forcing it to be allocated on the heap. I have no idea what that has to do with your question. Escape analysis should tell you what the compiler is deciding.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by clarifying that there is no memory leak in your program - there are extra heap allocations in your `bad` case compared to your `good` case, but after a garbage collection, all that memory is released. That means there is no leak.

But there are certainly more heap allocations.

There are two ways to make your `bad` case have as much heap usage as the `good` case:

1. declare the `data` variable as type `any`:

   ```
   var data any = "123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_123456789_"
   ```
2. declare the argument type of the method as `string`:

   ```
   type Interface interface{ Method(v string) }
   type Implementation struct{}
   func (i *Implementation) Method(v string) {}
   ```

In both above cases, you eliminate the need to convert a string to and interface for every invocation of the method, so the compiler will not perform a heap allocation per invocation.

The real reason that the `bad` case allocates more on the heap, is that in the `good` case, the Go compiler knows the exact method implementation, and analysis it. It sees that the method does nothing, and avoids the call to the method altogether. In the `bad` case, it sees a method call on an interface, and the static analysis doesn't consider that the only possible implementation at that point is the struct `Implementation`, so it cannot determine that the method call doesn't have any effect.

If you change the implementation of `Method` to do something with the argument, like storing it in a package-scoped variable, then the compiler cannot optimise the method call away in `good`, and `good` and `bad` will both allocate the same amount on the heap.

Comment: I tested more. the combination of interface and slice makes a problem. data:=1 is OK, while data:="1" or data:=[]{1} uses a lot of memory. Why?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, there is no memory leak - there are extra heap allocations.

Go compiler cannot predict the actual size of an interface, slice or map variable, so it allocates memory for it in the heap and not in the stack. Take a note, that a string in Go is a read-only slice of bytes.

Rus Cox has a great post about interfaces in Go
https://research.swtch.com/interfaces

Also you may be interested in William Kennedy's series of posts
https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/05/language-mechanics-on-stacks-and-pointers.html